# Can't reach my static ip from outside of country

Tags: static-ip

I want to access my cctv cameras from outside of country
everything looks fine on the cctv network like ports and static ip but i cant check my cameras on ivms-4500 application . please help
thank you

Comment: Unless you country has implemented special Internet blocking mechanisms it is not relevant in which country you are located in. If it doesn't work check if you can access your static IP at all or if it is a problem with the used application.

Comment: thank you very much